# Which naming convention should I pick when mainly using Twisted?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, twisted

I'm planning to start a project (a TCP server) using Twisted. I know Twisted uses `camelCase` for naming functions. The PEP8 says we should use `lower_case_with_underscores`. I know that the PEP8 was written after the Twisted coding standards, so they're not going to change a lot of code with the `camelCase` convention. There's just one thing that makes me doubt. Check out this quote from [here](http://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2012/10/a-tired-hobgoblin.html).

> If you're making a new Python project today, unless it is intended
>   specifically
> as extension for Twisted, you should ignore the
>   relative merits of these coding standards and go with PEP 8, because
>   the benefits of consistency generally outweigh any particular benefits
>   of one coding standard or another.

So how can I achieve consistency in my project if my code will use the PEP naming convention and the main framework that is going to take the 50 or 60 percent of my code uses `camelCase`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest going with `lower_case_with_underscores` because, that way, it will be clear when you are using the `Twisted` framework & when you are using your own code. This goes well with the quoted tip from Twisted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But won't that decrease my project consistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) -

> When in doubt, use your best judgment.
>   Look at other examples and decide what looks best.

This boils down to *you* i.e. the current project. It is actually a matter of personal choice. The PEP 8 or any other styleguide is basically, *a guide*. You'll have to judge as to what goes better with your situation.

Specific points that would matter, which I would like to mention are -

1. Do you have a lot a acronyms that would be used?
2. What is your project team comfortable with?

And, like I mentioned in my comment, using `lower_case_with_underscores` helps differentiate `Twisted` modules & your custom modules/functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read that many times. That's why the question. The PEP8 says I should go ahead with the Twisted naming convention. But Twisted says I should go ahead with the PEP8 naming convention. It's just about functions, because the convention for classes is the same. I don't care about variables / objects, because Twisted doesn't export that kind of names. Thanks again.

Comment: I am really getting confused for no reason. Sorry for the mess. Updating my answer to reflect the real question. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you.  Use your best judgement, whatever makes you and your team comfortable.

Except for the fact that [camelCase is objectively superior in every conceivable way](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2012/10/a-tired-hobgoblin.html), of course, and Python made a wrong turn at standardizing on underscores ;-).

Comment: Wow, an answer from the Twisted project founder. Thanks a lot. +1.

Comment: Use pep8 and ``import twistedFunction as twisted_function`` to correct the non-pep8-valid twisted imports, problem solved.